# Finding max and min value every N rows in columns of CSV data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this with ~5M rows:

```
11/8/2016       2.495418222 2.501995109 2.488331492 2.504259694
11/8/2016       2.495759632 1.213707641 2.137418322 2.501118589
11/8/2016       2.495565218 3.050992103 0.870950956 2.500971719
11/8/2016       2.494934557 2.500041484 2.489212707 2.455110626
```

I am trying to find both the max and min values of a 10000-row sample, and iterate until the end of the data. (finding a trend of multiple max and mins).
My code currently only grabs a value every 10000 rows instead of what I require above.

```
lcd = pan.read_csv('DAQ_Test_2016-08-11.csv',usecols=[0,2,3,4,5],skiprows=[0,1,2],na_filter=False)
lcd = np.array(lcd)
tslen2 = len(lcd[:,0])

rph2 = 57600
sfr2 = tslen2/((tslen2/rph2)*(2))   
currentdata = (lcd[0::sfr2])
```

Comment: I don't see where you grab the 10,000 rows.

Comment: Do you want a rolling window or slices? Rolling is max and min for rows 0 - 10000; 1 - 10001; 2 - 10002 ... or slices: 0 - 10000; 10000 - 20000; 20000 - 30000 ... ?

Comment: It's not exactly 10000 values, sfr2 is a variable that is calculated based on the amount of rows. (I just said 10000 for simplification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lcd = pan.read_csv('DAQ_Test_2016-08-11.csv',usecols=[0,2,3,4,5],skiprows=[0,1,2],na_filter=False)

# Group by every 10,000 rows
groups = lcd.groupby(pd.cut(lcd.index, range(0,len(lcd), 10000)))
groups.min()
groups.max()
```